# tikz-qtree: joining two lines at a node

Tags: tikz-qtree

I would like to create a structure like the one in the picture, where the `\draw` line connects two elements without a gap at the node. The closest I've gotten is:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=40pt]
        \Tree [.D [.\node(Bup){\ };  ] [.C [.A  ] [.\node(Bdown){B};  ] ] ] 
        \draw (Bup.south)..controls +(1,-4) and +(-1,1.5) ..(Bdown.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but it leaves a gap at both nodes. Plus the standalone pdf it creates has a lot of white space underneath the tree. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome. Use the `north` anchors to avoid the gaps, slightly different control points, and the `bbox` library to obtain a tight bounding box.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=40pt,bezier bounding box]
        \Tree [.D [.\node(Bup){\ };  ] [.C [.A  ] [.\node(Bdown){B};  ] ] ] 
        \draw (Bup.north)..controls +(1,-4.5) and +(-1,0.75) ..(Bdown.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works! I get an error for  ```\usetikzlibrary{bbox}``` though, saying this library could not be found.

Comment: @aktualitaet This means that the Aktualität of your TeX installation is not sufficient. You need to update it, the `bbox` library was only added recently.

Comment: Thanks for the info (and kudos on the pun). I'm using Overleaf, so I guess I'll just have to wait?

Comment: @aktualitaet I do not know anything about overleaf. Either you wait, or you copy `tikzlibrarybbox.code.tex` from [here](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/bbox) to somewhere where TeX can find it (I have no idea how that works under `overleaf`), or you ask the support for help.

Comment: Note that the `bbox` library was removed from TikZ with version 3.1.6 due to licensing issues: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/releases/tag/3.1.6